# How do I change image for small tile - Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

If standard (medium sized) tile is defined by

```
StandardTileData
```

What is it for the small tile?

(I want to change the background image of the tile based on some user setting.
I'm doing it like this for the medium tile, but what is the class that defines the small tile?

```
StandardTileData newTileData = new StandardTileData();
newTileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("appdata:AppIcon_final.png");
newTileData.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative);
ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
appTile.Update(newTileData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **FlipTileDate** in Windows Phone 8, there are `small, medium, large` tile in it.

```
FlipTileData flipTileData = new FlipTileData() 
{
    Title = title,
    Count = count,
    BackTitle = backTitle,
    BackContent = backContent,
    SmallBackgroundImage = smallBackgroundImage,
    BackgroundImage = backgroundImage,
    BackBackgroundImage = backBackgroundImage,
    WideBackgroundImage = wideBackgroundImage,
    WideBackBackgroundImage = wideBackBackgroundImage,
    WideBackContent = wideBackContent
};
appTile.Update(flipTileData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ShellTileData CreateIconicTileData()
{
    IconicTileData iconicTileData = new IconicTileData();
    iconicTileData.Count = 11;
    iconicTileData.IconImage = new Uri("/Assets/pizza.lockicon.png", UriKind.Relative);
    iconicTileData.SmallIconImage = new Uri("/Assets/pizza.lockicon.png", UriKind.Relative);
    iconicTileData.WideContent1 = "Wide content 1";
    iconicTileData.WideContent2 = "Wide content 2";
    iconicTileData.WideContent3 = "Wide content 3";

    return iconicTileData;
}
```

Hope this helps too.. 
Thanks and cheers.